# Property 'address' does not exist on type {} while going into production mode Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I was working on a site that used Angular 4. It worked fine until when i go to production mode. During production mode ng build seems to work fine but when i execute ng build --prod the it throws error. like this

[image: error image]

my view is something like this

```
<ul class="personal-info list-inline clearfix mb-5">
  <li><strong>Full Name :</strong>{{details.name}}</li>
  <li><strong>Birthday :</strong>{{details.birth_day}}</li>
  <li><strong>Address :</strong>{{details.address}}</li>
  <li><strong>Phone :</strong>{{details.phone}}</li>
  <li><strong>Email :</strong> <a href="">{{details.email}}</a></li>
  <li><strong>Job :</strong>{{details.job}}</li>
  <li><strong>Skype :</strong> {{details.skype}}</li>
</ul>
```

and my component is something like this

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  title = 'app';
  slider = {};
  specialities = {};
  works = {};
  details = {};
  image;
  html;
  image1;
  private url = "http://localhost/portfolio/api/home/data"

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(res => {
        this.slider = res.slider;
        this.specialities = res.specialities;
        this.works = res.works
        this.details = res.details;
        console.log(res);
      });
  }


}
```

i searched for the error but i cant find the solution. What could be done to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is looking for name, birth_day, etc. properties on the Object class, but they don't exist on the Object class. You need to declare the type of your objects as any and then Typescript won't complain about your property names. Like this:

```js
slider: any = {};
specialities: any = {};
works: any = {};
details: any = {};
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create a class  Details  and declare details as follow in the component,

```
export class Detail {
  name : string;
  .............
  etc
}
```

and inside the component,

```
details:Detail ;
```

Comment: Thanks. But the below answer worked so I did not tried this

Comment: yes the below answer will also work. but best practice is to define a class as suggested

Comment: Ok from now I will follow this